# Blazor - Bootstrap Alert not showing in some functions

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a small Alert component as a separate file AlertBox.razor

```
<div class="alert alert-@AlertType" role="alert">@AlertMessage</div>


@code {
    [Parameter] public string AlertMessage { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public aType AlertType{ get; set; }

    public enum aType{
        primary, //0
        secondary, //1
        success, //2
        danger, //3
        warning, //4
        info, //5
        light, //6
        dark //7
    }

}
```

I have successfully called the alert from one of my main pages, where it sits right at the top:

```
<PageTitle>Maintenance</PageTitle>
@if (ShowAlert)
{
    <AlertBox AlertMessage="@AlertMessage" AlertType="@AlertType" />
}
```

I set the properties and set the ShowAlert bool in a small funciton:

```
async Task AlertTask(string m, int t){

        //Set Parameters
        AlertMessage = m;
        AlertType = (AlertBox.aType)t;

        //Show Alert
        ShowAlert = true;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        ShowAlert = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Which is then called in functions that want to use it. This alert displayed correctly in this function (that also disables some other form fields.

```
public void cancelChanges(){
        //Disable the editing fields
        isDisabled = true;

        AlertTask("Update has been cancelled", 5);

        //Plenty of other stuff happens in here
}
```

But it doesn't work in this other function on the same page:

```
public async void saveChanges(){

        try{
            //Update Query, works
            int updResult = await Procs.procBankCodeItemDescriptionUpdate(editDetail.BankCodeLookupId, editDetail.ItemDescription, editDetail.OriginatorReference, editDetail.OriginatorParticulars, editDetail.OtherPartyReference, editDetail.OtherPartyAnalysisCode, editDetail.SendEnquiriesToEmailAddress);
            
            //Log the change, also works
            updResult = await Procs.procAuditLogMessageInsertAsync("Maintenance", DateTime.Now, "Details for " + editDetail.ItemDescription + " sucessfully updated by " + currentUser.UserName + ". ");
            //Call alert in same way as Cancel Function, doesn't work
            AlertTask("Details have been updated successfully.", 2);
        }catch(SqlException e){
            //Log failure
            int insResult = await Procs.procErrorLogMessageInsertAsync("Maintenance", DateTime.Now, "Error updating record: " + e.Message);
            //Call function to show failure, doesn't work either.
            AlertTask("There was an error updating the payment details", 3);
        }

    }
```

Both functions are called by button click events, different buttons on the same form control.

```
<!--TODO: Replace these three spans with proper styling on the buttons, once I'm smart enough to know what to do.-->
            <div class="row p-2">
                <span class="col"/>
                <button class="px-1 btn btn-primary col" type="button" id="btnSaveEdit" disabled="@isDisabled" @onclick="saveChanges">Save Changes</button>
                <span class="col"/>
                <button class="px-1 btn btn-secondary col" type="button" id="btnCancelEdit" disabled="@isDisabled" @onclick="cancelChanges">Cancel Changes</button>
                <span class="col" />
            </div>
```

I have tried adding an `await` keyword before the call: `await AlertTask("Details have been updated successfully.", 2);` but this did not work either.

I also tried setting the properties for AlertMessage and AlertType in the Try/Catch then calling the alert function after the Try/Catch using the set properties (just in case there's an issue starting tasks inside the try block, but this also didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make three changes:

```
//public async void saveChanges(){
  public async Task saveChanges(){
```

and (2x)

```
//AlertTask("Details have been updated successfully.", 2);
  await AlertTask("Details have been updated successfully.", 2);
```

Using `aync void` is detaching your code path from the update logic. An extra StateHasChanged inside AlertTask() could also fix this but awaiting is better.

All Blazor events support awaitable handlers.